# Create own Uri with parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8.1, uri

I'm tried to create my own Uri with some parameters. I wrote this but it doesnt work:

```
string url = "http://arweb.elwin013.com/api/rest/tag/getNearestTags?latitude=" + lat.ToString("0.00000") + "&longitude=" + lon.ToString("0.00000") + "&distance=100000";
var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Elaborate on "doesn't work."

Comment: It doesnt download the json. I wrote then it's only work with uri without paremeters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `ToString` method converts the number to a string with a `,` in it. This breaks the server, having it return a http-500 error.

To fix your code make sure you use [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18sthszb(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts an [InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) like so:

```
decimal lat = 1.25M;
decimal lon = 2.25M;
string url = "http://arweb.elwin013.com/api/rest/tag/getNearestTags?latitude=" + 
   lat.ToString("0.00000",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 
   "&longitude=" + 
   lon.ToString("0.00000",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 
   "&distance=100000";
var u = new Uri(url);
Debug.WriteLine(u); // use this to verify how your real Url would look
var response = await client.GetAsync(u);
```

You might also use the [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class to construct your Uri:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder {
     Scheme = "http"
     , Host ="arweb.elwin013.com"
     , Path = "api/rest/tag/getNearestTags"
     , Query = String.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "latitude={0:0.00000}&longitude={1:0.00000}&distance=100000",
        lat, 
        lon)
   };
var response = await client.GetAsync(builder.Uri);
```

That might keep things a little bit better organized, maintainable, if you have to buildup complex Uri's.